# Autoinsert a python skeleton

Tags: python, elpy, auto-insert

I start my python files (.py) with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and sometimes

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    somefunc()
```

having done it some hundreds of time manually I decided to automate it in Emacs.

```
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert
     '("\\.\\py\\'" . "python skeleton")
     '(""
       "#!/usr/bin/env python3" \n
       "# ")))
```

I thought that putting the above snippet in the `.emacs` file
would be enough.
A new `.py` file is still empty.

I temporarily removed all Elpy related setups from my `.emacs` file
having proved (I guess) that Elpy doesn't contribute to the problem.

Using Emacs 24.5.1, Python 3.5.3, Debian 4.9.130-2, Elpy 1.28.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command `auto-insert` with <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `auto-insert`. This of course defeats the purpose of "auto-inserting". What you want to do is enable `auto-insert-mode`, in addition to defining your new auto-inserts. You can do this by adding `(auto-insert-mode 1)` to your init file. (I'd put it just above your template)

```lisp
(auto-insert-mode 1)
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert
     '("\\.\\py\\'" . "python skeleton")
     '(""
       "#!/usr/bin/env python3" \n
       "# ")))
```

You can view the documentation for `auto-insert-mode` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `auto-insert-mode`.

```
auto-insert-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function
in ‘autoinsert.el’.

(auto-insert-mode &optional ARG)

Toggle Auto-insert mode, a global minor mode.
With a prefix argument ARG, enable Auto-insert mode if ARG is
positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.

When Auto-insert mode is enabled, when new files are created you can
insert a template for the file depending on the mode of the buffer.

[back]
```

Also, the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/) as a has a [good page of inspiration](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) on `auto-insert-mode`.